# Triangle inequality for $\ell^1$ metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing, triangles, image-processing

How can I show that the distance satisfies the triangle inequality?

Where the distance is given by:
$$d(p,q) =  |p_1-q_1| + \cdots + |p_n-q_n|$$

Triangle Inequality: $\forall x,y,z\Bigl( d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)\Bigr)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove the triangle inequality for this metric it is sufficient to note that each of $|x_i-z_i| \le |x_i-y_i|+|y_i-z_i|$ by the simple 1-dimensional triangle inequality.

Comment: Should I show each point like this?$|x_i-z_i| \le |x_i-y_i|+|y_i-z_i|$ I have to prove that is not 2 edges sum smaller other a edge. I need general formula

Comment: Just sum over all $i$ for a'general formula'.

Comment: I say , a point has more dimensions  $$d(p,q) =  |p_1-q_1| + \cdots + |p_n-q_n|$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the triangle inequality for the absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Could you give more hint , actually I need more details.

Comment: @herobee1965 Where are you stuck?

Comment: Should I show each point like this?$|x_i-z_i| \le |x_i-y_i|+|y_i-z_i|$ I have to prove that is not 2 edges sum smaller other a edge

Comment: yes, that is what I and the other answer are driving at

Comment: I need a general formula. the point could has a infinite dimensions

Comment: you have written down a metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is finite dimensional. Do you understand that if $|x_1-z_1|\leq |x_1-y_1|+|y_1-z_1|$ and $|x_2-z_2|\leq |x_2-y_2|+|y_2-z_2|$, then $|x_1-z_1|+|x_2-z_2|\leq |x_1-y_1|+|y_1-z_1|+|x_2-y_2|+|y_2-z_2|$? Can you extend this to $n$ terms?

Comment: $ |x_1-z_1| + \cdots + |x_n-z_n| \leq |x_1-y_1|  + |x_1-z_1| + \cdots + |x_n-y_n|  + |x_n-z_n| $  That is proof?

Comment: You just wrote down the conclusion, so as long as you explain how you got there (using the triangle inequality for the absolute value and adding things together), then yes, I would take it

Comment: Actually I didnt understand to explain how I got there

Comment: @herobee1965 I can't help you if you don't tell me what is confusing you, at this point we have pretty much the entire proof in these comments.

Comment: I hope proof that if we sum for $y_1 ... $ and $z_1 ... $ then left side will 0 but bigger side will be sum of all edges. the proof true.?  $0 \leq |x_1-y_1| + |x_1-z_1| + |y_1-x_1| + |y_1-z_1| +  |z_1-y_1| +   |z_1-x_1| \cdots + |x_n-y_n| + |x_n-z_n| + |y_n-x_n| + |y_n-z_n| +  |z_n-y_n| +   |z_n-x_n|$